# Is the movie 'Beyond Skyline' based on the book 'A Plague of Demons'?

Tags: beyond-skyline, a-plague-of-demons

Is the movie [*Beyond Skyline*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_Skyline) (2017) based on the book [*A Plague of Demons*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1829054.Plague_of_Demons) (1964), written by Keith Laumer?

Both are using human brain, but in the book it's not robots but tanks.

Comment: Skyline was the worst film I've ever seen that isn't Starcrash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The film script was an original creation of writer/director Liam O'Donnell. He cites a host of sci-fi influences on his writing **but not Keith Laumer**

> *This movie is kind of a love letter to my favorite movies. Die Hard,
> Terminator 1&2, Predator, Aliens, Independence Day, Starship Troopers,
> Indiana Jones 1-3, Big Trouble in Little China. Not sure if it's just
> because you will always love the movies you see when you are ten years
> old or that the movies I saw when I was ten were the best.*
>
> <sub><sup>[AMA: Liam O'Donnell](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/7jtcte/i_am_liam_odonnell_the_writerdirector_of_beyond/dr9djsp/)</sup></sub>

And

> *It's always changing... but the ones I've watched the most are
> definitely Raiders of the Lost Ark, Conan The Barbarian, Die Hard, Big
> Trouble in Little China, Predator...*
>
> *But also Terminator, Star Wars, The Thing, Alien, Aliens, Mad Max,
> Road Warrior, Fury Road... and so on.*
>
> <sub><sup>[AMA: Liam O'Donnell](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/7jtcte/i_am_liam_odonnell_the_writerdirector_of_beyond/dr9djsp/)</sup></sub>

---

The genesis for the original Skyline was a drunken weekend in a high-rise apartment.

> *So, lesson learned there, we started thinking along the lines of
> Paranormal Activity - shooting something in Greg's new penthouse condo
> which overlooked Los Angeles. It seemed like an ideal place to watch
> the world end, so that really was the genesis of the story. Waking up
> one morning, seeing something strange outside your window and then
> everything just unravelling before your eyes.*
>
> *After we came up with the general concept, the co-writer Joshua Cordes
> and I wrote separate three-page treatments. We took our favourite bits
> from each and got to work. Colin and I were both obsessed with Lost at
> the time, so you can see some of that influence in the flash forward
> opening and the mystery of the blue lights. But from the very first
> time we pitched the logline, we all knew it was kind of special.
> Everyone saw the potential of this low budget setup with huge visuals
> and it just took off right away.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Liam O'Donnell interview: Skyline, Beyond Skyline](https://www.denofgeek.com/uk/movies/beyond-skyline/53602/liam-odonnell-interview-skyline-beyond-skyline)</sup></sub>

Comment: Welp.  That explains how Skyline ended up as such a bad movie.  Inspired by the travesty that is "Starship Troopers," it could only be worse.  :)

Comment: @JRE - Compared to this train-wreck, Starship Troopers looks like a masterpiece of subtlety and understatement